# Nested list comprehension from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a nested list comprehension to get a nested list A from a master dictionary and a sublist. Not sure if I am explaining it right...

I have:

```
master_d = {'d0': {'p': [1], 'q': [2]}, 'd1': {'p': [2], 'q': [5]}}

coefs = ['p', 'q']
```

Trying to get

```
A = [[1,2],[2,5]]
```

I can index into the dictionary with

```
print(master_d['d0']['p'][0])
```

I am sure it can be done with a list comprehension but been pulling my hair out trying to get list A in one line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
[[i for l in d.values() for i in l] for d in master_d.values()]
```

This returns:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
[ sum([ v[c] for v in master_d.values() ], []) for c in coefs ]
```

or using purely list comprehensions

```py
[ [ x for l in [ v[c] for v in master_d.values() ] for x in l ] for c in coefs ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to concatenate all values insides the `dict`'s elements:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add
A=[reduce(add, d.values()) for d in master_d.values()]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use pandas you can do something like this in python 2. In python 3 you will need to use `list` to convert the `map`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(master_d)
map(lambda z: reduce(lambda y, x: y + x, df[z], []), df)
```